# wp_title is blank on all pages in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I am relatively new to wordpress. I have an issue where the wp_title is displaying blank on ALL pages of my site.

I've see a few posts addressing the page title not displaying on the index page, but haven't found anything related to it not displaying on ALL pages of the site.

Using the code below, my title tag is rendered with the site name, but no page name:

```
<title>
    <?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";
</title>
```

Like I said, I'm new to using Wordpress so there's a very high chance I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: Do you have anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: I just checked - nothing at all, @Lee

Comment: Ended up solving this issue for myself by installing the Yoast SEO plugin, which in hindsight is better for my situation anyway. Doesn't explain why wp_title wasn't displaying, but at least it works now

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ?
printf (get_bloginfo('url')), printf (get_bloginfo('description'), printf ('sitename').

Comment: That doesn't return the page name though, eg. 'About', 'Contact', 'Blog' etc. etc.